# Sending JSON with AJAX to Flask Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, flask

```
 url: '/upload',
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(pdata),
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "text",
```

is what I'm using to POST the JSON and it is sending it with the double quotes needed

but in flask

```
content = request.get_json()
```

gives me content with the double quotes swapped with single quotes

for example {"S":[],"R":[]} goes to {'S':[],'R':[]}

it is something I'm doing wrong or do I need to somehow convert this back to two quotes if I want to send this to a javascript program?

Comment: Just use `json_loads(some_data)` when sending back. This will convert Python dictionary to json

Comment: I just got it to work with json_dumps is there a difference between the two?

Comment: sorry my bad. `json_loads(some_data)` converts JSON format to python obj. `json_dumps(some_data)` serializes python obj literal as a JSON formatted stream. Read more about it here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request.get_json() returns a python dictionary with values of double-quoted items represented as strings. When you print a python string it's printed with single quotes by default.

When the dictionary is converted back into JSON format you will get doublequotes.